# Dynamic img src

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Alright, so I have 3 different Avatars that I want to be randomly assigned to users but constantly so for each user, what I decided was best is to modulus the user id by 3 and set to whatever that is, so this is the code

```js
<img src={`Avatar${user_id % 3}`}/>
```

However, the src is being parsed as a string, rather than a reference to my imported `Avatar3`
To clarify, the result I'd like is what would be normally coded as
`<img src={Avatar3} />`
But what I'm getting is what would be coded as `<img src="Avatar3" />`

How can I fix this? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a imageMap and reference that.

```
const imageMap = {
  1: Avatar1,
  2: Avatar2,
  3: Avatar3,
}

<img src={imageMap[user_id % 3]}/>
```

Comment: I was hoping to do it on a one-liner like I was attempting but I guess that's not possible, your answer works fine tho, thanks !